# Painting Standard Deviation as a shadow in background of sapui5 Line chart

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I plotted some test performance data in my sap.viz.ui5.Line chart and it works as I wanted it to do.
Databinding is with a JSON model, generated by an ajax call. 
Now I want to show something like a light bar in the background showing the standard deviation of the test results.
Code for Line chart:

```
var oDataset = new sap.viz.ui5.data.FlattenedDataset("ds", {
        dimensions : [ {
            axis : 1,
            name : "time",
            value : "{time}"
        } ],
        measures : [ {
            name : "result",
            value : "{result}"
        } ]
    });
var oChart = new sap.viz.ui5.Line("chart", {
        width : "1200px",
        height : "750px",
        title : new sap.viz.ui5.types.Title({
            visible : true,
            text : "Test performance by unit"
        }),
        dataset : oDataset,
        noData : oTextView
    });
```

The plot currently looks like this (example):
[image: plot example]

I want it to be like just a horizontal bar with mean as "center" and the standard deviation around it.
Anybody with an idea?

EDIT:

What I want to achieve is something like this (may not be the stddev but it's an example):
[image: hopefully the outcome]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might somehow use the "reference line", but I think there is no property to the define it horizontally and acutally it is vertically: https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/sample/sap.viz.sample.TimeBubble/preview

But I think the approach to display a second line would be easier, define a second measure:

```
var oDataset = new sap.viz.ui5.data.FlattenedDataset("ds", {
        dimensions : [ {
            axis : 1,
            name : "time",
            value : "{time}"
        } ],
        measures : [ 
          { name : "result",
            value : "{result}" }, 
          { name : "result2",
            value : "{result2}" } 
          ]
    });
```

Then Calculate the standard deviation in your service (and assign always the standard deviation value to your service) -> this will show a horizontal line (because all values are the same) - the same you did it for result, you simple define result 2, which will show up another line (and the same values make the line horizontal)

If you got an SAP backend, you have to extent your entity with another property (transaction SEGW).

Further examples:

Line Chart: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/test-resources/sap/viz/Charting.html 

Data Set Definition: https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/sample/sap.viz.sample.Line/code

Comment: Adding a second line for the mean would have been my first solution too, but I'd like to have something like a colored area with the standard deviation around the mean for usability reasons.

Comment: I am not that mathematical expert to know what you mean without seeing an example, but try check this link: search for "VizFrame" https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html - there you get several latest highend examples what is possible with charts.

Answer (score -2):

Other better option is to use reference lines. I think it's easier and it suits more to your needs:

oVizFrame.setVizProperties({

plotArea: {

referenceLine: {

line: {

primaryValues: [{

value: 80,

color: "#0000FF",

type: "line",

label: {

text: "Min Value",

}

},

{

value: 100,

color: "#FF0000",

type: "line",

label: {

text: "Max Value",

},

}]

}

}

}

})

Comment: As I explained in the first answer (which is exactly the same as yours), a reference line was NOT the answer to the problem. I wanted a colored area as  a background of the area between my reference lines.
Also by now (in the last 2 years since I asked the question) the viz lib changed quite a lot so this question should be read with care.